# How to correct this if exists query?

Tags: t-sql

Do you know why this piece of code returns syntax error? A subquery executes properly.

```
 if exists (
 select ad_ulica from #adresy_sprawdzenie where DN=1 and RN=1 and  
 ad_ulica=(select ad_ulica from #adresy_sprawdzenie where DN=1 and    
 RN=2)        
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one problem and fixed it in the following:

```
if exists (
 select ad_ulica from #adresy_sprawdzenie where DN=1 and RN=1 and  
 ad_ulica in (select ad_ulica from #adresy_sprawdzenie where DN=1 and    
 RN=2)        
 )
     begin

     -- tsql here

     end
 else
     begin

     -- tsql here

     end
```

Instead of `...and  ad_ulica =(select ad_ulica from #adresy_sprawdzenie where DN=1 and RN=2)`

I replaced the equal sign with `in`.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you get an error saying:

> subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

Here's a query that should get you the results you want:

```
if exists (
    select 1
    from #adresy_sprawdzenie
    where DN=1
    and RN in (1, 2)
    group by ad_ulica
    having count(distinct rn) = 2
)
```

Using `group by` and `having` with `count(distinct rn)` checks if there are at least two records with the same `ad_ulica` with `dn=1` where one have `rn = 1` and the other have `rn = 2`.

Comment: This is the error I receive: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 86
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: What's in line 86? The code I've posted is not tested but I don't see a syntax error in it.

Comment: There's a subquery in line 86.

Comment: Well I can't help you debug your code if I don't see it... I'm a developer, not a mind reader...